# How to fix missing libsasl.dll when using cUrl?

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to use curl with c++ and I've gotten as far as downloading the version here:

http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl-devel-msvc

I've set up and linked everything following these instructions:

http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/

However when I run the program I'm met with an error:

```
The program can't start because libsasl.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I've been searching all day trying to find where this libsasl.dll is supposed to come from but I can't find it anywhere.  Does anyone know where I can get this dll, or how I can get curl to work in Visual Studio?

Comment: Probably You need to install it. This link might be useful: http://dlldb.com/libsasl-dll/

Comment: @MantoshKumar's link works, but its download link, `http://wilfur.se/dlldb/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/libsasl-dll.zip` is broken. I was about to say this works: `http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libsasl`, but it seems to be crapware on top of the dll...

Comment: It seems this does work, just *don't* download the crapware "fixer". Use the "advanced" download and just put it in the proper Windows system folder. http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libsasl